# How to draw polygons sharing exact same edges (borders) using Leaflet Draw

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps, leaflet.draw, geojsonio

Using geojson.io page I want to draw some districts/countries.
I'm drawing each district separately as there is no multipolygons in Leaflet Draw. However when I'm drawing the borders even with maximum zoom - the borders will never be exactly the same. Coordinates will differ to some extend which is natural. Hence when I am downloading the data in topojson , the data are not valid to display meshes between different districts

How to achieve the goal to have the borders always with the same coordinates?

For example it could be achieved by having the markers visible during drawing and just picking up the one I'm interested in(on a same border) by mouse click - the same way the shape is finished.

I have downloaded the source code, read it (it is nice), searched through docs and thinking how to adjust it for my goal but I'm lost :/

Comment: Why not just turn a shapefile of these districts/countries into a geojson? Why do you have to draw?

Comment: Because I need very specific custom  districts (city level) that are not available in any tile provider. Even if it was available I still need to have full control/adjustments

Comment: Tiles? Do you know what a shapefile is? Do you know the coordinates of these areas?

Comment: To be more specific: lets assume we have a city and I need to split that city for areas that are not yet determined anywhere. Only I know what the split is going to be: "like from this tree to this particular building is area A, and from that playground to that bridge is area B". So to some extend I know the coordinates by picking it from the map directly. Yes, I do not have any experience with shapefiles and have no idea it can help in any sort. I know they can have data I can transform to geojson/topojson but I do not think any file has data I want to project.

Comment: so in other words: I want to obtain coordinates with exact borders first by drawing it on the map. RIght now I am looking at Leaflet.Snap and it seems promising but not sure yet the coordinates for borders will be the same

Answer (score 0):

Leaflet.Snap did the trick.
I was afraid that snapping will be not exact for the borders but it  is :)